# how to make VM Public to network?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Further my question on Askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025100/i-want-to-use-vm-like-a-localhost-serve

how to make this VM is Public for all network?

in other words, how to access to the Local Server installed at VM from mobile phone for example?

Answer (score 0):

From your original question, you appear to be using a VirtualBox NAT adapter as one of the adapters for your Guest.

With this NAT adapter, you should be able to set up port forwarding from the Host to the Guest through VirtualBox. Once this is done, any device that can access your Host (and the appropriate port) should be able to access your Guest's service(s) (VirtualBox essentially acts as a router in this instance).

---

*Note that if you decide to use a Bridged Adapter, the port forwarding steps given below for NAT are unnecessary. Accordingly, Bridged Adapters will have their* Port Forwarding *button disabled.*

---

**Port Forwarding For VirtualBox NAT**

1. Select the appropriate virtual machine in the VirualBox Manager interface (e.g. *Ubuntu Server 16.4*).
2. Under *Settings...* → *Network*, select the correct virtual adapter using NAT.
3. Expand the *Advanced* settings and press the *Port Forwarding* button (below the *Cable Connected* checkbox).

   *ex. VirtualBox NAT Adapter Settings*

   [image: VirtualBox NAT Adapter Settings - Screenshot]
4. In the *Port Forwarding Rules* window, create one or more new forwarding rules (using the green "plus" icon on the right). Enter the following items:

   - *Rule Name* — This can be whatever you like.
   - *Protocol* — Set the protocol for your Guest's service as appropriate (TCP is used for HTTP, SSH and FTP).
   - *Host Port* — The port that VirtualBox listens to (on the Host) for traffic to redirect (i.e. this is your "external" port for interacting with your Guest's service).
   - *Guest Port* — The port that VirtualBox redirects traffic to for your Guest (i.e. the "internal" port on which your Guest's service listens).
5. As noted, you can add as many rules as necessary. Press *OK* when finished.

   *ex. Port Forwarding Rules For VirtualBox NAT*

   [image: Port Forwarding Rules For VirtualBox NAT - Screenshot]

Once this port forwarding is set up correctly, barring any other issues, your Guest's service(s) should be available through *Host_IP:Host_Port*. You can then (re)direct devices on your network as necessary to access this IP/Port combination.

> How can I access my local server installed as a VM from a mobile phone, for example?

If your phone was on the same local wifi network as your Host (ex. *1.2.3.4*), given the example rules above, you could access e.g. *1.2.3.4:8080* on your phone's browser.

For remote access (i.e. from your phone's mobile network), you would need additional port forwarding via your router to forward requests from outside your local network to e.g. *1.2.3.4:8080* (which would then be forwarded to your Guest).

**Caveats**

If you have trouble connecting to your Guest's service(s):

- You may need to configure your local firewalls (on the Host, Guest or elsewhere on the network).
- Additional port forwarding outside VirtualBox may be required (e.g. for access outside your LAN).
- You may need to forward additional ports in VirtualBox or configure your Guest's server software (FTP in particular is a likely candidate for this).

If you want name resolution to work (e.g. *www.yoursite.com*), you will need a properly configured DNS server as well.